Using a three terminal PCB slide switch for on/off control
Most of on/off PCB slide stiches has 3 pins(terminals). And I want to use this such switch as on/off switch for the following part of a circuit:

Above SW1 is the 3-terminal slide switch I want to use to on/off control input power to the voltage regulator PS1.
But the electrical rule checker is giving "pin not connected" error. Is this just fine if I connect pin 3 to pin 1?

Electrically, that is fine.  However, the DRC might still have a problem with it.

You can use the "X" no-connection flag.
Check the official KiCad guide at this link - These flags should be placed on symbol pins which are meant to be left unconnected. "No-connection" flags indicate to the Electrical Rule Checker that the pin is intentionally unconnected and not an error. They also affect schematic connectivity for stacked symbol pins.

Great, didnt know that thanks!

Can you put relavante information in the post so if the link goes dead the answer is still usable?

Most CAD programs have a "No Connection" marker that you can use to tell the ERC function that you really didn't want to connect something.
The ERC "errors" are really just warnings to you that something may not be what you intended.  The ERC errors will not prevent you from proceeding to the PCB layout program (and DRC errors there will not prevent you from generating the PCB manufacturing files).
It is certainly good practice to clear all ERC and DRC errors, but they can be ignored if you are sure the circuit or PC board is as you really want it.
